# Absolute positioning :after and transforming it not aligning it in center

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Hey guys I had to create simple dots on a carousel like so:

[image]

And hence I used the following method:

```
.banner-nav-dots > li > a {
    position: relative;
}

.banner-nav-dots > li.active > a:after {
    content: '';
    background: #6e2c91;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Now that should have really centered the dot , but as can be seen on **[THIS LINK](http://codeandcode.co/demo/cryosave/html/V1-archive/)**, they are not exactly aligning in the center. Why? Why are they not aligning in the center?

**Below is a MVCE**:

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #6e2c91;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
.circle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #6e2c91;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='circle odd-numbered'></div>
```

I am more interested in the ***WHY*** part. Can somebody explain please?

P.S. this absolute position method combined with transform has always worked for me, but just on this instance its caused this issue and I don't know why. Checked both in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Seems to be due to odd numbered width (`15px`) on the parent circle. This means the 50% values for `top` and `left` on the child would become fractions. The browser is probably doing some rounding down and thus the positioning is not accurate. If you want it perfect, give an even numbered width.

Comment: @Harry thanks buddy ! thats the answer ! perfect .. please add it as an answer , just copy paste it .. or else i'll do :)

Comment: Let me see if I can find some reference for how browsers handle fractional top/left values. Without that the answer would look cheap.

Comment: @Harry sure absolutely :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be due to a ***combination of odd numbered dimensions*** for parent container (`height: 15px`, `width: 15px`) and the ***50% value for positioning attributes on child*** (`top: 50%`, `left: 50%`). This means that the ***actual calculated value will be*** 5.5px ((15px - 4px) / 2) for left and top (15px - 4px due to `box-sizing: border-box` also being applied on the parent).

When such fractional values are encountered, it looks like the browsers round-off the value. I couldn't find anything about this in the specs (whether it should be a round-up or down) and there aren't many recent articles on the net also about this particular thing. However, I did manage to find [this old article](http://tylertate.com/blog/2012/01/05/subpixel-rounding.html)  which says that each browser treats them differently. Some round it down whereas others round it up. Either ways, the child element is not going to at the exact center.

The fix for this case seems to be to set an even-numbered value for the parent's dimensions.

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #6e2c91;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.odd-numbered {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
.even-numbered {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}
.circle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #6e2c91;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h4>Odd Numbered Dimensions - PROBLEM </h4>

<div class='circle odd-numbered'></div>

<h4>Even  Numbered Dimensions - NO PROBLEM </h4>

<div class='circle even-numbered'></div>
```

Comment: I understand the phenomenon, but what if I have to use odd-numbered dimensions? Will there also be a way that fits the odd-number case?

Comment: No, not if you want a responsive design. Fixed width margins won't cut it when it comes to responsiveness. And, surely a 1px addition/deduction in dimensions to change from odd number to even number will not result in a big design problem.